# Prove tangent of angle in scalene triangle inscribed in right triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I'm given the following:

[image: Drawing]

**EDIT: The actual problem was "Show that $\tan(\alpha+45^\circ) = 1 + \frac{120\sqrt{2}}{x})$", which I had already proved:**

From this I can see that $\tan{(\alpha + 45^\circ)} = \frac{AB}{AC} = \frac{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}+120}{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}} = \frac{\frac{x+120\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}}{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}} = \frac{x+120\sqrt{2}}{{x}} = 1 + \frac{120\sqrt{2}}{x}$.

I've been toying around with dropping a perpendicular from a point $E$ on $CB$ to $D$, and vice versa, to make a right triangle $\triangle CDE$ from which I could determine $\tan{\alpha}$ and hopefully show that the relation of the sides has to equal that of the outer triangle. But no luck with that so far.

I also see that the angle $\angle CDB$ is $135^\circ$. If bisecting that would give me right angles onto $CB$, i.e. be equivalent to dropping a perpendicular from $CB$ onto $D$, both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ would have to be $22.5^\circ$. However, I haven't been able to prove this, and even assuming it has led me nowhere.

Are the above arguments flawed, or am I just missing out on some obvious geometric relation? Or, given that this is part of a larger problem from calculus class, do I need another approach altogether?

Answer (score 0):

You've proven that $\tan(a+45^{\circ})=1+\frac{120\sqrt{2}}{x}$

Then  $\tan(a)$ must be less and cannot be equal to $\tan(a+45^o)$.

You can subtitute $\tan(a+45^{\circ})=\frac{\tan(a)+\tan45^{\circ}}{1-\tan(a)\tan45^{\circ}}=\frac{1+\tan(a)}{1-\tan(a)}$ and find the value of $\tan(a)$.

Comment: Well pointed out, thank you. Re-reading the original problem I discovered I had mixed up the angles. I have edited the original post to reflect this.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

in $\bigtriangleup$ADC AD=X .SO WE GET AC=AD=$\frac{X}{\sqrt{2}}$

- SO AB= $\frac{X}{\sqrt{2}}$+120
- tan(45+$\alpha$)= $\frac{AB}{AC}$= $\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}$+120/$\frac{X}{\sqrt{2}}$[putting the value]
- OR $\frac{1+tan\alpha}{1-tan\alpha}$=$\frac{x+120\sqrt{2}}{x}$[According to formulae]
- FROM THIS WE GET tan$\alpha$=$\frac{120\sqrt{2}}{2x+120\sqrt{2}}$[image]